# Subset rows of a data frame that contain numbers in all of the column

Tags: r, subset

I want to get a subset of my dataframe by keeping rows that have numeric in all columns so

```
>small
     0    16h    24h    48h
ID1  1    0      0   
ID2  453  254    21     12  
ID3  true  3     2      1
ID4  65    23    12     12
```

would be

```
>small_numeric
     0    16h    24h    48h  
ID2  453  254    21     12  
ID4  65    23    12     1
```

I tried

```
sapply(small, is.numeric)
```

but got this

```
0      16h    24h    48h   
FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
```

Comment: Please use `dput` for `small` to make it reproducible (i.e. `dput(small)`)

Comment: `small[!rowSums(is.na(sapply(small, as.numeric))),]`

Answer (score 5):

Using:

```
small[!rowSums(is.na(sapply(small, as.numeric))),]
```

gives:

> ```
>       0 16h 24h 48h
> ID2 453 254  21  12
> ID4  65  23  12  12
> ```

What this does:

- With `sapply(small, as.numeric)` you force all columns to numeric. Non-numeric values are converted to `NA`-values as a result.
- Next you count the number of `NA`-values with `rowSums(is.na(sapply(small, as.numeric)))` which gives you back a numeric vector, `[1] 1 0 1 0`, with the number of non-numeric values by row.
- Negating this with `!` gives you a logical vector of the rows where all columns have numeric values.

---

Used data:

```
small <- read.table(text="     0    16h    24h    48h
ID1  1    0      0     
ID2  453  254    21     12  
ID3  true  3     2      1
ID4  65    23    12     12", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fill = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

---

For the updated example data, the problem is that columns with non-numeric values are factors instead of character. There you'll have to adapt the above code as follows:

```
testdata[!rowSums(is.na(sapply(testdata[-1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))),]
```

which gives:

> ```
>       0  16h  24h  48h   NA
> ID2 ID2   46   23   23   48
> ID3 ID3   44   10   14   22
> ID4 ID4   17   11    4   24
> ID5 ID5   13    5    3   18
> ID7 ID7 4387 4216 2992 3744
> ```

Extra explanation:

- When converting factor-columns to numeric, you will have to convert those to character first. Hence: `as.numeric(as.character(x))`. If you don't do that, `as.numeric` with give back the numbers of the factor levels.
- I used `testdata[-1]` as I supposed that you didn't want to include the first column in the check for numeric values.

Comment: Still getting all rows (unfiltered)

Comment: @marie It works on the example data. If it doesn't work on your real data, please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) in your question, so I can see why it doesn't work.

Comment: > dput(head(testdata,7))
structure(list(`0` = structure(1:7, .Label = c("ID1", "ID2", 
"ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID6", "ID7"), class = "factor"), `16h` = structure(c(1L, 
6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "13", "17", "4387", 
"44", "46", "true"), class = "factor"), `24h` = c(0L, 23L, 10L, 
11L, 5L, 13L, 4216L), `48h` = c(0L, 23L, 14L, 4L, 3L, 24L, 2992L
), `NA` = c(NA, 48L, 22L, 24L, 18L, 2L, 3744L)), .Names = c("0", 
"16h", "24h", "48h", NA), row.names = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", 
"ID4", "ID5", "ID6", "ID7"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: This is great, thank you so much for the explanation, it all makes much more sense now. I have now used read.csv with stringsAsFactors=FALSE which avoids using the more complicated code further down the line.